# Magento - Get Product SKU's and quantities on order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created an event observer on the "sales_order_place_after" event, which fires when the user places an order in Magento's checkout. That event triggers my observer, which needs to get the following information, which is then sent to an external inventory management system.

Information needed: *The SKU and quantity of every product on the order*

I have included part of my observer model below.  I am accessing the order object.  I can get all the items in the order, but how do I get the SKU for every product that makes up the order.  For example, with a simple product, this is very easy.  **However, with a bundled or configurable product I do not know how to access the children that make up that bundled product with their SKU's and quantities.**  That is the info I need for both bundled and configurable products.  I need the SKU and quantities of the children that were selected.  For the life of me, I can't figure out what method to call to access that information.  I wish there was something like: `$item->getBundleChildrenSkuQuantity();`

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $joomecomPacket = array();

    if ($order->getTotalItemCount() > 0) {
        $items = $order->getAllItems();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $productType = $item->getProductType();

            switch ($productType) {
                case 'bundle':

                break;
                case 'configurable':

                default: // simple products
                    if (isset($joomecomPacket[$item['sku']])) {
                        $joomecomPacket[$item['sku']] += $item['qty_ordered'];
                    } else {
                        $joomecomPacket[$item['sku']] = $item['qty_ordered'];
                    }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a break after your configurable case. The default case is executing for configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); // gives only parent items

foreach ($items as $item){

$childItem = $item->getChildren(); //do something with $cildItem like $childItem->getSku() etc...

}
```